# Segmentation Fault in TrainCascade on OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, haar-classifier

I'm getting this weird error. I have 437 positive images and 3019 negative images.

The positive images all taken of 35x35 pixels.

This is the command that I use:

> opencv_traincascade -data data -vec lv.vec -bg bg.txt -numPos 437 -numNeg 3019 -numStages 10 -w 35 -h 35

if I use `-featureType LBP`, it hangs on the 0-stage not calculating anything. If I remove it, this is what happens:

[image]

When I try to retry the process, I get:

[image]

**What I've tried:**

- Make the `numNeg` lower.
- Trying to put the `numPos` near to `samples / numStages`.
- According to the previous thing, re-low the `numNeg` to 300.

But the same *Segmentation fault: 11* appears.

I haven't got this error before.

Do you know what am I doing bad?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the whole OpenCV and binaries solved the problem.